# How to get part of JSON for KendoDataSource

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-datasource

I need to fill a **KendoListView** from a external server and I need to use just part of the response I am reading for a Java Servlet

```
       var srcListView = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
            read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "MainServlet",
                data:{event:"Test"},
            },
        },
    });
```

And the response is:

```
{
  "status": "ok",
  "response": {
    "trucks": [
      "A6U-905",
      "AHF-888",
      "AHP-779",
      "buzz"
    ]
  }
}
```

**I need just the trucks array** for kendoListView, I am using Kendo-ui, How I can do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an alternative to what [@DontVoteMeDown](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1267304/dontvotemedown) said about using [`schema.parse`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.parse) you can use a simpler solution for cases like this where you don't need to process the result but just return what is in an element. This solution is define [`schema.data`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.data) as the name of the field containing the data. In your example:

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "MainServlet",
                data:{event:"Test"},
        }
    },
    schema: {
        data: "response.trucks"
    }
});
```

I recommend using `schema.parse` when you need to do some transformation on the data received and `schema.data` when is simply returning some sub-element of the received JSON.

Comment: I forgot about that way, it is lot better tho.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`dataSource.schema.parse`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/schema#schema.parse) to filter the data to be used in the widget:

```
new kendo.data.DataSource({
    transport: {
        read: {
                dataType: "json",
                url: "MainServlet",
                data:{event:"Test"},
        }
    },
    schema: {
        parse: function(data) {
            return (data && data.trucks ? data.trucks : []);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks the answer i almost correct just I did this and work..        schema: {
               parse: function(data) {
                return (data && data.response.trucks ? data.response.trucks : []);
            },

Comment: @DavidDominguez great!!

Comment: @DavidDominguez check out OnaBai's answer.